# How to add 7 days to current date?

Tags: magento-1, date, locale

I need to save to db current date & "current date + 7days" values. For this I'm using following function. But how to add 7 days to this.

```
 Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
$res = Mage::getModel('rad_inventorypieces/reserve');
$date = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
$res->setCreatedDate($date);
$date->addDay('7');
$res->setExpiryDate($date);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In OOP style:

```
$date = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
$date->addDay('7');
$date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); //Returns representation of date
```

Comment: its giving result fine when echoing..but when i saving  to db  its saving like this 2014-11-07 02:58:41

Comment: when echo..Oct 24, 2014 2:48:44 AM,Oct 31, 2014 2:48:44 AM fine.

Comment: could post the lines please?

Comment: Yep go with this one, cleaner solution than mine.

Comment: $res=Mage::getModel('rad_inventorypieces/reserve');$date = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
      $res->setCreatedDate($date);
      $date->addDay('7');
      $res->setExpiryDate($date);

Comment: it must be 
setCreatedDate($date->toString('Y-M-d H:m:s'))

Comment: It is wrong way : current date : Dec 29, 2015 11:25:28 PM and output : 2016-25-5 23:i:28

Comment: This is not correct because you get server date if your magento server is located in other time zone do not get the correct date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo $date . '<br>';

$nextDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date." +7 days"));

echo $nextDate . '<br>';

$res=Mage::getModel('rad_inventorypieces/reserve');
$res->setExpiryDate($nextDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underlying Zend methods:

```
$now = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(), Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
$now->set(strtotime('+7 days', $now->toString(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP)), Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
$now = $estimate->toString(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

This will give you an epoch time output of 7 days from the time the code runs, you can use this in `date()` or wherever you need to.

Comment: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object

Comment: I can assure you the above works, where exactly are you running the code?

Comment: in observer file.place order after event

Answer (score 0):

here's mine

```
$Date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 days'));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'));
```